# Insert Data to SQL Server Compact

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a VB.NET Program that inputs data to a SQL Server CE local database (`*.sdf` file).

My code is this:

```
    Imports System.Data.SqlClient
    Public Class Form1
    Dim myConnection As SqlConnection
    Dim myCommand As SqlCommand
    Dim ra As Integer

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        myConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source= Database1.sdf")
        myConnection.Open()
        myCommand = New SqlCommand("Insert into website('"TextBox1.Text"')", myConnection)
        ra = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Updated")
        myConnection.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        TextBox1.Text = My.Settings.SaveWebsite
    End Sub
End Class
```

I get three errors during compile:

> Error 1:
>   Argument not specified for parameter 'connection' of 'Public Sub New(cmdText As String, connection As
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, transaction As
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction)'.
>
> Error 2
>   Comma, ')', or a valid expression continuation expected.
>
> Error 3
>   Value of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' cannot be converted to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction'.

This is first time I am using VB.NET and I'm hoping someone might know what I'm doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for starters: when targeting SQL Server **Compact** Edition (the `*.sdf` file), you need to use `SqlCeConnection` and `SqlCeCommand` (not `SqlConnection` or `SqlCommand` - those are for the full-blown SQL Server, non-compact)

Secondly: your `INSERT` statement is incorrect - the correct SQL syntax would be:

```
INSERT INTO Table (col1, col2, ..., colN) 
VALUES(val1, val2, ..., valN)
```

Comment: The SQLCe Connection was the issue. Thanks a ton.